# How to compare two school classes with a survey?

Tags: survey

I am doing research at a school. I want to see what effects a certain teaching method has on the students. For this I have one class which is the control group and another class in which I am applying the teaching method. At the end of the experiment I want to take surveys in both classes and compare them to each other, to see if the teaching method has had any effects on the class. The survey I have made is a 1-5 likert scale. What would be the best way to compare the two classes? What tests would I have to run etc.

Either in excel or SPSS

Comment: What is the desired outcome you're looking at?  Are you the one teaching the classes?

Comment: What questions do you have? For instance, why not just see if the mean or median rating in the classes is different?

Comment: @Demetri Pananos I’m hoping the teaching method has some positive effects on the class so the teacher/school can implement it. I am not the one teaching, I have instructed a teacher to apply the teaching method. My goal is to advice the school whether or not it is a good idea for them to implement the teaching method in most of their classes

Comment: What is the positive effect you are assessing?  Students liking the class?  Scoring higher on some test?  Is it the same teacher teaching both classes?  WE need more details in order to provide the most effective way forward.

Comment: @Dave they are questions about for example how motivated they are, if they like the classes etc. 
Comparing the mean in the classes is a good idea indeed, thank you! So simple yet it didn’t come to my mind. Will this provide accurate results?

Comment: @Dave the mean for a likert variable is perhaps not the best indicator.  I could have a mean of 3 by having all students answering 3 or by having a split between 1 and 5. Though the means are the same, the information on the intervention is very different between the two.  Please let OP provide additional details as to the intent of the intervention

Comment: @David Pananos effects i am assessing are: motivation in class, test results, discipline and atmosphere in classroom.

Comment: @ Demotte Pananos it is indeed the same teacher!

Comment: Sorry I misspelled your name

Comment: Unless either (1) you measured each class *before* teaching began or else (2) determined class membership randomly, it will be impossible to attribute any differences to the teaching method.

Comment: @whuber I get what you mean. Because the control group is of course still a different class than the other group so you can’t really compare the two objectively

Comment: @whuber the teacher however said the classes were very much alike so I suppose the method I am using (comparing control group with teaching method group) would still work? Of course no person is the same so no class is the same, but if the classes are not that different from each other I really don’t see a problem here

Comment: What you're saying, then, is that the validity of all your work ultimately depends on the teacher's assertion that the classes are "very much alike."  No matter how credible the teacher might be, that isn't going to get you very far.  Certainly you can compare the two groups in any way you please.  Just don't attribute any differences to the teaching method, because you haven't the logical support for that.

Comment: Results are more likely to reflect whether the _teacher_ prefers the new method rather than whether the _students_ do. Also, in practice, one teacher's implementation/ interpretation of the method may be quite different than that of another teacher. // Unclear whether there are several Likert-scale questions on the questionnaire or one; whether achievement scores will also be used. What exactly will you analyze at the end?

Comment: @BruceET all questions on the questionnaire are Likert-scale questions. There will be around 20 questions. They are about the student’s motivation in the class, whether they like the atmosphere, whether they like the teacher (and their teaching method) etc. In the end I hope to assess the following effects: motivation, number of absences/too late for school, grades, mental health in class (does the teacher make them feel stressed) and how they like the ambiance in the class. Mental health, motivation and ambiance will be assessed through the questionnaire.

Comment: Any standard test will assume that the individual observations are independent, and if there is interaction between classmates, this will be violated, potentially in ways critical for the result. So I wouldn't recommend trusting any standard test in this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming students are at the same school and taught by the same teacher, it may be sufficient to simply perform a Chi-square test.

For each outcome, the data will look approximately like

| Outcome | Control | Intervention |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |

The assumption here is that the columns are independent of the rows; that the proportion of students answering 3 for instance does not matter on if you are in the control or intervention arm.  The alternative hypothesis is that the rows and columns are dependent; that the proportion of students answering in a particular category depends experimental arm.

If you reject the null of this test, you can example the distribution of answers to make claims such as "Students were x% more likely to rate the class a 3 or higher on enjoyability" for example.

This assumes that the class has sufficient sample size to make the chi-square test viable.  There are some rules of thumb regarding expected cell values which may threaten internal validity of the study by making the test stasitic not chi-square distributed.  If so, you could resort to multinomial regression which can give more or less the same answer assuming the sample is sizable enough.

Whuber makes a good point; causal conclusions are unlikely to be valid unless students are randomized to class.  If you have a teacher which is known for handling students with behaviour problems particularly well, this can effect interpretation.

Comment: yes I totally forgot to mention, the classes are indeed randomized as that just happens each school year. The teacher was given a universal protocol, so it will tell them how to act accordingly to each situation. So each situation will be treated almost the same. Do you still think this can effect interpretation? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If students are randomized to class, then you should be able to statistically compare the two classes.

Comment: The proposed chi-squared test is for _one_ question, and it ignores the ordinal nature of Likert data. If difference is found, how do you say whether Control or Intervention scores 'better'?

Comment: @BruceET  I believe you’re right. With the chi-squared test you can’t really compare the two classes on all questions at once, so it will be hard to draw general conclusions. Do you perhaps have a method in mind in which I can compare the two classes overall and for the effects I am measuring (motivation, ambience, mental health)? Because I have multiple questions for each effect

Comment: Then, as appropriate, you may want to compare average Likert scores (over similar questions). If you are using nonparametric tests, there may be fewer difficulties with ties by using averages.

Comment: @BruceET Do you mean that I should compute mean scores and then perform a non parametric test using those scores?

Comment: Mean scores of some appropriate kind may at least allow you to run a statistical test. But see @whuber's comments above. It's still not clear to me that your "randomization" is sufficient for a valid study, so the test may not be meaningful. Do you have any kind of achievement test given to all students so you could at least check classes were 'equal' before the study. //Perhaps larger issue is whether there were differences in teaching method beyond the ones you know about. Maybe teachers made special efforts to help make your method a success in the study--efforts not guaranteed in future.

Comment: @BruceET You made a good point about the validity of my research. I will certainly write in the discussion that my results are probably not valid. Unfortunately, the experiment is already done so there is really nothing I can change now. However I still need to submit this paper. Would you still recommend I perform a statistical test or would this be useless? If not, what specific test do you have in mind that I could run to compare the groups for each effect? Say the mean score for motivation of one group is 4.5 and for the other it is 3.5 would I be able to perform a t-test?

Comment: @BruceET Or could I also compute the mean scores for each effect for each respondent and then perform a Mann Witney u this way?

Comment: Not exactly sure what that means. Can you show example for one student?

Comment: @BruceET Say I have 5 likert type questions for motivation. The student answers strongly agree = 5 for the first question, agree for the second question =4, disagree for the third question = 2, agree for the fourth question = 4 and strongly agree = 5 for the 5th question. That student’s average score for motivation would be (5+4+2+4+5)/5 = 4.0 From my understanding, you can also let spss calculate this for you by computing mean scores over those variables (questions).

Comment: I believe this average could be treated as an interval scale instead of ordinal, so would I be able to perform statistical tests on this data?

Comment: The $\chi^2$-test also assumes that the single entries, i.e., the individual students that are counted, are independent, and this is not given if there is interaction within classes.